# Navigation Drawer Activity not loading all fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

So I'm using the Out-of-the-Box navigation Draw Activity built into Android studio. Doing so I managed to successfully add a 4th fragment in addition to the three provided along with navigation to it.

However, when I go add the 5th...That's when things get strange. Repeating the exact same process yields no results. Even stranger, during one bout of troubleshooting I deleted two of the pre-existing destinoids under the AppBarConfiguration.Builder. Only to have the navigation work flawlessly on the first four still.

This left me perplexed.

So I'm left now with Out-of-the-box code, that as far as I understand should not be working, but is. Yet is working up to four destinations, but not five.

I've copied my methods from my first duplication to the nines when attempting the second. I'm Lost at this point so any advice would be quite welcome.

Here is my AppBarConfiguration.Builder:

```
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_aPlus, R.id.nav_bPlus)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

Here is the aPlus fragment, this is the one that works

````
    private APlusViewModel APlusViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        APlusViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(APlusViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_plus_fragment, container, false);

        return root;
    }
}```
````

This is the bPlus Fragment, this is the one that does not work.

````
```public class bPlusFragment extends Fragment {

    private BPlusViewModel BPlusViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BPlusViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BPlusViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b_plus_fragment, container, false);

        return root;
    }}```
````

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Did you check the graph file?

Comment: ^This is the Answer^

I did not! It works now! Not sure why the 4th addition didn't have me interface with this file before. I'll have to learn how the graph file works now. Thank you for the help!